# Managing session state on site with several servers?

Tags: networking, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am currently in the design phase where we have several servers that make up our system and I need to work out what is the best way to store session information so that each of the servers can get access to it. Session information is basically a guid for the session id and a list of user group names.

The main client applications are web and mobile apps.

I have the following configuration:

A master server where all users log in and the session object is filled with the user group information that corresponds to the user. There could be up to 10,000 users at peak log in.

Slave servers which contain archiving content and most users would then via the UI be talking directly to the slave servers. The slave servers need the session information which is initially determined on the master server.

One option was to move the session data for each log in to the slave servers and cache it on the slave, then each slave could work independently and it will not need to reference the master server.

The other option is to have central database which contains the session information but since our databases are on each server (we don't have a separate machine to act as a database server), each slave will have a remote connection string back to the master server database. No doubt this will slow things down if I have to query the database remotely from the slave server.

I then have the situation where I need to clean up sessions but in general I don't expect more that 25 MB of data at the peak log in.

We could have up to 10 slave servers.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Is this a web, desktop, or mobile app? Why can't you take one or two of the "slave" servers and have them serve as a DB server and host multiple apps on a single server? You haven't, IMO, provided enough information to determine a "best" solution.
If it's a web app and all you're storing in session is a guid and some roles you could use a cookie in the client. But, again, that answer may not be correct depending on your application. Really need more info.

Comment: How much information can I store in a cookie? Currently it is just a guid and some roles, but in the future it could be more data. Also, I thought it would be quicker if I had the data cached on each server rather than make remote database connections to another server.

Comment: Also by using one of the slaves as a database server, then the application and the database server wont be competing for resources (CPU, disk, memory) and each slave would be hitting this slave server for data. By caching, then each slave has a copy of the data and I avoid this problem.

Comment: I would think a session server of some sort to manage that information would be most reliable if you need to share accurate information between the servers. What technology are you writing these apps in? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We have a flex client and a html5 client for tablets. Backend is IIS7, serviceStack for rest based communication and PostGres for a database. How would a session server work? Is the data persisted in a database or do I have to access it via web services?

Comment: "...this will slow things down if I have to query the database remotely..."  I'm not sure what the application is or what your SLAs are, but querying a database remotely is a common architecture and I don't know why you are trying to avoid it.  Is there some other reason you are avoiding it?

Comment: We don't have database server (separate machine), so I would be hitting another server with a remote connection, which I felt may slow things down as an application server is running where the database is.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 7.0 here is a technet article that outlines two approaches (a session server or using SQL server):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754032(v=ws.10).aspx

I question the need to have 10 web servers running with 10 seperate databases running on them. Granted, I don't know anything about the application you're writing and there may very well be a good reason for it.

Here's how I'm seeing it (with my admitted limited knowledge of your application).

10,000 possible concurrent users hitting 1 authentication server that will then redirect them to one (or more?) of 10 servers could potentially cause bottlenecks. What if a majority go to one of the servers? What if a large number all try to log in at the same time?

Here's a stab at a different architecture:

```
                           [LoadBalancer]
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WebServer]   [WebServer]   [WebServer]  -------------> [SessionServer]
                           [LoadBalancer]    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [AppServer]   [AppServer]   [AppServer]   [AppServer] -------^

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DBServer]
    [DBServer](backup)
```

I write that not knowing what class of machines these are; they may not be suitable to be a DB server.

Well, it's early here and I'm only on my second cup of coffee. That may or may not be helpful, I hope it is.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for all your help. Having not worked in SOA before your help has been invaluable.